# How can I create Firebase Dynamic-Links by two different links?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to create a dynamic link with two different original links.

One original link for Android, e.g: `android://mePage/account`

One original link for ios, e.g: `https://mePage/account`

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually?authuser=0) of Firebase Dynamic-Links, I found there is a optional parameter `al`, and `al=android_link`.

So I create a Dynamic Link by manually constructing a URL:

```
https://myapp.app.goo.gl/?link=https://mePage/account&al=android://mePage/account
```

But maybe I misunderstand, it doesn't work.I have no way to resolve the android link from the `al` key.

So:

1. What does the `al` parameter really mean?
2. Any way I can acquire the parameter?
3. If it does not work, is there any way I can create a Dynamic Link with two different links?

There is a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgPX1.png) to show what I saw.
And I found some extra [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALZc5.png) from another [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener?authuser=0).

Answer (score 2):

There is no `al` parameter, did you meant `afl`? `afl` specifies the link, where navigation will happens if your App is not installed on Android. So that instead of navigating to PlayStore you can navigate to your page.

Answering your question about Android and iOS specific deep links: we do not have such feature. The same deep link will be passed to Android and iOS Apps.

If you want to separate the data for your Apps, you can use deep link constructed like this:

```
https://mePage/account?ios=<ios specific base64 data>&android=<android specific base64 data>
```

Than you can wrap this deep link inside Firebase Dynamic Link.
Not sure this provide enought value, but I do not know your requirements.

If you feel that you need this feature and Firebase Dynamic Links do not support it, feel free to open support ticket or describe your use case here. We always open to improvements and new feature suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the 'al' parameter from [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually?authuser=0). Please see the example URL:>https://app_code.app.goo.gl/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&al=android_link][&afl=fallback_link]

Comment: @gumaola Can't find the 'al' parameter there. Can you make screenshot and circle where you see it? Maybe I see staging website so content is different...

Comment: Yes, I upload some images to show where I saw it. Please check the question which I have updated.

Comment: I see, I am going to remove this parameter from docs. We had it previously, but not supporting "al" anymore. See my answer for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

For those who are still looking like me,
as per the docs, https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually
You **can** specify a different fallback link for IOS/Android using IFL/AFL params.

> ifl
> The link to open when the app isn't installed. Specify this to do
> something other than install your app from the App Store when the app
> isn't installed, such as open the mobile web version of the content,
> or display a promotional page for your app.
>
> afl
> The link to open when the app isn't installed. Specify this to do
> something other than install your app from the Play Store when the app
> isn't installed, such as open the mobile web version of the content,
> or display a promotional page for your app.